# Secure Email in C#

Tags: c#, email

I have a code for sending email through code, its as follows:

```
string subject = "SecureEmail: URS Scheduler - ";            
string body = @"Message: My Message";    
try
{
    SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    //msg.SubjectEncoding.
    sm.Host = "email.myhost.com";

    //Add Sender
    msg.From = new MailAddress("abc@myhost.com");
    //Add reciepents
    sendMailToUsers(msg, "pqr@myhost.com");
    //send message
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Subject = subject;   
    msg.Body = body;
    sm.Send(msg);
```

I am able to send message but its not encrypted, its a plain Text.

When I go to my Outlook mail client and Send Mail with above recipients and body, and subject starting with "SecureEmail:", I get an Encrypted Email with a button "Open Message". When I click on Open Message it redirects me to https://web1.zixmail.net/s/e?b=domain&m=encrypted msg and other info,then I login into it and and able to see the plain text of mail body.

Please help me in getting above behaviour through my code.

Comment: Unless you're exchanging public and private keys with your recipient I'd go on a limb and say email is not secure no matter what outlook says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your company is using [ZixMail](http://www.zixcorp.com/support/zixmail/), and your Outlook has a plugin to enable this. If you want to send ZixMail from C#, you'll need to use their toolset and API. Reffer to ZixMail documentation and support.

Comment: Any other way to send secured mail programmatically?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_encryption, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME .